# Viewing a large field in a query in SQL management studio with ZOOM?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can anyone help? I am using SQL management studio (sql server 2008) to run queries and some of the fields that come back are varchar(max) for example and it has a lot of information - Is there a zoom feature to open the window and show me the contents with vertical and horizontal scrollbars?

I remember there was, i thought it was F2 but i must have been mistaken as it doesn't work

Now i have to scroll horizontal on the field  and its really difficult to see everything

Also some of the fields contain new line codes etc so it would be great if the zoom feature would display the info using the new line codes etc

Any body know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can return just the column using the SQL Statement, and put the output into Text Mode (CTRL T) which will show the value with line breaks.  You'll also need to tell SSMS that you want to see more than 2000 characters (I think that's the default) by changing that in the Options for SSMS.